# Preg Relplace only replace instances of text with a trailing space

Tags: php

I have a preg_replace question. I am using preg_replace to generate contextual links in text blocks using the following code:

```
$contextualLinkStr = 'mytext';
```

$content = 'My text string which includes MYTEXT in various cases such as Mytext and mytext. However it also includes image tags such as `<img src="http://www.myurl.com/mytext-1.jpg">';`

```
$content = preg_replace('/' . $contextualLinkStr . '/i', '<a href="foo.html">\\0</a>', $content);
```

The preg_replace is working well on the text and generating the relevant links while retaining case but it's also generating a link within the URL of the image tag. I was thinking If I simply added a trailing space to the expression in the preg_replace function it would fix it due to the fact that all text instances will have a trailing space whereas no image urls will, as follows:

```
$content = preg_replace('/' . $contextualLinkStr . '/i' . ' ', '<a href="foo.html">\\0</a>' . ' ', $content);
```

But this doesn't work. Can anybody tell me how I make the trailing space a condition of the match?

Thanks in advance.

Jason.

Answer (score 0):

I've just worked it out guys. I was being daft. For reference the relevant code is:

```
$content = preg_replace('/' . $contextualLinkStr . ' /i', '<a href="foo.html">\\0</a> ', $content);
```

Thanks.